# How to strip the time off a date column in Powerpivot 2013

Tags: powerpivot

I'm attempting to strip the time from my date column in Powerpivot 2013. I tried this:

=DATE (YEAR([Completion Date]), MONTH([Completion Date]), DAY([Completion Date]))

However, this is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I think there's a format option in the ribbon that always you to format dates different ways.

Comment: Format does not change the underlying data. Is your goal to simply not display the time portion, or is it to truncate an existing time portion? The function you supplied in your post will truncate an existing time and return a date-time with time = 0 (aka midnight). The version of the Tabular engine in PP for Excel 2013 only has a date-time data type, so you have to be careful not to change display formatting of a date-time when you actually want to truncate the time.